# Piecewise function calculation with variable in integration interval

Tags: integration, change-of-variable, piecewise-continuity

I have this:

$(f*g)(x)=\int_{x-\frac12}^{x+\frac12} f(t)dt$
where $t = x-y$

and $f(x)$=\begin{cases}
 0&\text{if}\, x\ < a\\
 \exp(-x)&\text{if}\, a \leq x \
      \
\end{cases}

I have problem with splitting this integral, the end result is supposed to be a function with three pieces. Any ideas? What I have trouble understanding is how to split this integral when we have $x$ in the interval.

Kind regards Pontus

Comment: Is y a constant?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta I think we assume x takes a fixed value when we do the variable change from (x-y) to t, so then y shouldnt be a constant. But Im not 100% sure!

Comment: Have you not been given any more information in the question? For example, do we know anything about a?

Comment: Integration variables are dummy so, the question, stated in this way, does not make much sense.

Comment: You should clarify what "$\int_{x-\frac12}^{x+\frac12} f(t)dt$
where $t = x-y$" means! Because for example $\int_{x-\frac12}^{x+\frac12} f(x+y)d(x+y)$ makes no sense...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich the expression is equal to (f*g)(x), forgot to add that part my bad

Comment: Saying it's a convolution may clarify what you mean, or not, but it doesn't change the fact that "$\int_{x-\frac12}^{x+\frac12} f(t)dt$
where $t = x-y$" makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided:

If $\> x+\frac{1}{2} < a \quad$ (i.e. $\> x < a-\frac{1}{2}$)
\begin{align*}
    \int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^{x+\frac{1}{2}} f(t) \mathrm{d} t &= \int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^{x+\frac{1}{2}} 0 \> \mathrm{d} t = 0
\end{align*}

If $\> x-\frac{1}{2} > a \quad$ (i.e. $\> x > a +\frac{1}{2}$)
\begin{align*}
    \int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^{x+\frac{1}{2}} f(t) \mathrm{d} t &= \int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^{x+\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \mathrm{d} t = \mathrm{e}^{-(x-\frac{1}{2})} - \mathrm{e}^{-(x+\frac{1}{2})}
\end{align*}

If $\> x \in \left( a-\frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2} \right) $
\begin{align*}
    \int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^{x+\frac{1}{2}} f(t) \mathrm{d} t &= \int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^{a} f(t) \mathrm{d} t +  \int_{a}^{x+\frac{1}{2}} f(t) \mathrm{d} t = \int_{x-\frac{1}{2}}^{a} 0 \> \mathrm{d} t +  \int_{a}^{x+\frac{1}{2}} \mathrm{e}^{-t} \mathrm{d} t  =  \mathrm{e}^{-a} - \mathrm{e}^{-(x+\frac{1}{2})}
\end{align*}

Combine to get the resulting function with three pieces.